# How do I fit a big picture in a smaller space in Visual Basic?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In a report that I'm designing, I have created a small image (height:0.2083"; width:1") on which I want to show a picture! But of course, the picture is quite big and when I link to it, it goes outside of the border.

I have tried shrinking the picture down by using paint, an online resizer, as well as word. In paint and the online resizer, the picture gets shrunk, but the quality is bad. In word I shrink the picture and then save as, but the original dimensions are kept, yet the quality stays high. When I print out the picture that was shrunk in word, the quality is high. When I insert into a word file either of the pictures that were shrunk elsewhere, and then print, the quality is bad.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to shrink the picture right before it gets put into the image, but yet still keep the original picture dimensions in my file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, change the image property size mode from clip to zoom.